Why is SQLPackage suddenly including every scalar function in my SSDT project for ALTER in my deployment?
I have a SQL 2019 SSDT project with a large number of scalar and table-valued functions. Suddenly yesterday, my Windows TFS (on prem) deployment project's SQLPackage scripting step is suddenly including every scalar function in the project (~300) in the deployment script (with ALTER). I spot-checked the first dozen - in every one, the current compiled definition in the target database is identical to the definition SQLPackage intends to execute. I checked the git repo - I don't see any commits that change the project's sqlproj file. Anyone seen anything like this before?

Are the quoted identifier and ansi nulls properties the same in both the project and database? If not, an ALTER may be used to change the settings.

I will check it out. A coworker also suggested that the project database compatibility may have changed in an earlier commit

The Data Service Provider -  - in the SqlProj file had been changed from Sql140 to Sql150. I reverted that change and the noise disappeared. The question of how to properly move the provider forward without re-introducing that issues reamains for now but is a separate issue.
